# Can I say "dispose" (without "of") to mean dumping things?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

I had always thought that one must say "dispose of" when referring to getting rid of something, until I came across this article by the government of Australia:

> In 2001, 19.0 million tonnes of waste were **disposed to** landfill, and
>   by 2007 this had grown to more than 21.3 million tonnes.
>
> Other indicators show that during 2006–07, nearly half (48%) of all
>   waste was **disposed to** landfill.

http://www.abs.gov.au/ausstats/abs@.nsf/Lookup/by%20Subject/1370.0~2010~Chapter~Landfill%20(6.6.4)

Now, I know that "dispose" can be used without "of" to mean "incline to" or "set in readiness", but it seems not the case here. Maybe it is an Australian thing?

Apparently, "dispose" without "of" is also being used in UK Parliamentary documents to mean the same thing:

https://books.google.com.hk/books?id=LmplFjtTKmcC&pg=PA179&lpg=PA179&dq=disposed+to+landfill&source=bl&ots=rDx0nzkfzj&sig=ZUWHsn0grVxZRkDfBu1bG24tEkk&hl=zh-TW&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj_hdbFsNrUAhUCupQKHeIJAEw4ChDoAQg6MAM#v=onepage&q=disposed%20to%20landfill&f=false

Or should I say "dispose of sth to somewhere" or "sth is disposed of to somewhere" instead?

Many thanks!

Comment: It might be OK in Australia, but in the US "disposed to" means roughly the same as "inclined to".

Comment: It is not that uncommon, but probably limited to trash-talking professionals. MSDS disposal info often reads this way. "13. DISPOSAL CONSIDERATIONS:
Dispose to incinerator. This product is not a hazardous waste. If recycled, silver is not a
waste." http://amepox-mc.com/cache/files/1298911294_MSDS-NanoSilver_AS__50.pdf

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. Some dictionaries almost support that Australian use but generally, rubbish is always *disposed of*.

Please be careful with, eg, *dispose* can be used without *of* to mean *incline to* or *set in readiness*.

Does *I will* dispose *my troops thus…* mean *incline to* or *set in readiness* or anything like either?

Comment: Yes, it means precisely *set in readiness*.  That is almost certainly why that meaning is listed in the dictionary. "... being still under the impression that he should be able to come suddenly upon General Taylor's force at Agua 'Nueva, and to cut it up before it could be suitably disposed for battle." https://books.google.com/books?id=MbZXAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA26&dq=%22disposed+for+battle%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjKvcWO0KrVAhUMET4KHddsD9QQ6AEIKDAA

Comment: Um…æ thanks for that, Phil. You're entirely right, as I knew, which proves I must have been up too late.

My apologies to one and all.